# Database query optimization (MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, join

I have three tables.

1. Radar data table (with id as primary), also has two columns of violation_file_id, and violation_speed_id.
2. Violation_speed table (with id as primary)
3. violation_file table (with id as primary)

I want to select all radar data, limited by 1000, from some start interval to an end interval, joins with violation_speed table. Each radar data must have a violation_speed_id.

I want to then join with the violation_file table, but not each radar records corresponding to violation_file_id, some records just has violation_file_id of 0, means there's no curresponding file.

My current sql is like this,

```
$results = DB::table('radar_data')
    ->join('violation_speed', 'radar_data.violation_speed_id', '=', 'violation_speed.id')
    ->leftjoin('violation_video_file', 'radar_data.violation_video_file_id', '=', 'violation_video_file.id')
    ->select('radar_data.id as radar_id',
      'radar_data.violation_video_file_id',
      'radar_data.violation_speed_id',
      'radar_data.speed',
      'radar_data.unit',
      'radar_data.violate',
      'radar_data.created_at',
      'violation_speed.violation_speed',
      'violation_speed.unit as violation_unit',
      'violation_video_file.video_saved',
      'violation_video_file.video_deleted',
      'violation_video_file.video_uploaded',
      'violation_video_file.path',
      'violation_video_file.video_name')
    ->where('radar_data.violate', '=', '1')
    ->orderBy('radar_data.id', 'desc')
    ->offset($from_id)
    ->take($max_length)
    ->get();
```

It is PHP Laravel. But I think the translation to mysql statement is straight away.

My question is, is it a good way to select data like this? I tried but it seems a bit slow if the radar data grows to a large value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the proper indices set this is largely the way to go, the only thing that's not 100% clear to me is what the `offset()` method does, but if it simply adds a `WHERE` clause than this should give you pretty much the best performance you're going to get. If not, replace it with a `where('radar_data.id', '>', $from_id)`

The most important indices are the ones on the foreign keys and primary keys here. And make sure not to forget the `violate` index.

Comment: offset is part of limit in mysql - I take it the framework would not change this -- as in limit 10 offset 20

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix: According to the docs using `skip()` will give you the `OFFSET` in a query: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset Also, since he's passing `$from_id` I would assume it's actually a where query/filter instead. Otherwise the `$from_id` would be wrong

Comment: don't really know Laravel, but I do know sorting can kill your performance :-p

Comment: Neither do I, database performance I know but Laravel... never used it :P

Comment: I used doctrine ( bad experience)  and after that query builders are ugly to me. lol

Comment: Hi thanks. I think for Laravel offset & skip are doing the same thing. Sorry for the misleading $from_id, it is just a bad name. What I intended to do was an offset, used for pagination. Will this offset affect performance if radar_data is very large? Thanks.

Comment: I think I will change the way from offset count to the where statement, just need to get the largest id in the old page. Hope this will make things faster?

Comment: If the offset is large it will be very slow. It's best to avoid using the database offset at all cost. Internally the database will fetch all rows and throw out the ones it won't use.

Comment: Hi I tried where statement, something like where('radar_data.id', '<', $from_id). Because I am using desc, so it must be <. Then it's still same, if $from_id is small, it will be fast, if $from_id is large, it will be slow. Shall I use something like where('radar_data.id', '<', $from_id) and where ('radar_data.id', '>', $some_guess_id_that_close_to_1000_smaller_than_from_id) ?

Comment: Yes, that might help a bit as well, it will be able to use the index more effectively to filter the results. The general rule of thumb is to filter as much as you can using indexes so your database has little to process.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of the query often relies on the use of proper indexing on the `joining clause` and `where clause` used.

In your query there are 2 joins and if the joining keys are not indexed then you might need to apply the following

```
alter table radar_data add index violation_speed_id_idx(violation_speed_id);

alter table radar_data add index violation_video_file_id_idx(violation_video_file_id);

alter table radar_data add index violate_idx(violate);
```

The ids are primary key hence they are already indexed and should be covered